# Set of errors when running a docker container

Tags: php-fpm, slow-connection, alpine

I have been asked to make a couple tweaks to a legacy PHP project that runs inside a docker container. In order to make those tweaks, I am trying to get a local working copy of the app and associated container running.

The docker container runs Alpine linux. I try to go to my index page and the browser just spins forever, with the following repetitive log output looping for as long as the request is active:

> php-fpm_1        | [25-Apr-2018 17:35:54] ERROR: failed to
>   ptrace(ATTACH) child 25: Operation not permitted (1) php-fpm_1
>   | [25-Apr-2018 17:35:54] WARNING: [pool www] child 25, script
>   '/usr/src/app/web/app_dev.php' (request: "GET /app_dev.php") executing
>   too slow (2.455295 sec), logging php-fpm_1        | 172.23.0.3 - 
>   25/Apr/2018:17:35:50 +0200 "GET /app_dev.php" 404 php-fpm_1        |
>   [25-Apr-2018 17:35:55] ERROR: failed to ptrace(ATTACH) child 24:
>   Operation not permitted (1) php-fpm_1        | [25-Apr-2018 17:35:55]
>   WARNING: [pool www] child 24, script '/usr/src/app/web/app_dev.php'
>   (request: "GET /app_dev.php") executing too slow (2.423747 sec),
>   logging php-fpm_1        | 172.23.0.3 -  25/Apr/2018:17:35:49 +0200
>   "GET /app_dev.php" 404

... etc ...

I found a [different serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/883082/php-fpm-slow-log-error-failed-to-ptraceattach-child-operation-not-permitted) that recommended manually running `audit2allow` -- a utility I have never used -- in order to fix a similar issue. But Alpine linux does not come with that utility, nor is the APK package manager present in my container. Before I go through the considerable work of installing those utilities, I want to know:

Is `audit2allow` even the way to go with this, or is there another likely solution?

=====

**Edit:** As Gerald commented, the audit2allow tool is part of selinux, which is not present in this copy of Alpine. So there must be a different way around this bug.

Comment: audit2allow is used to resolve problems with selinux. AFAIK Alpine doesn't use selinux (by default).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: Thanks. Running `sestatus` does indeed show an error message about hte command not existing, so I'm assuming you're right about this. You probably just saved me quite a bit of debugging time.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this was an app problem rather than an environment problem. I needed to symlink a folder full of static assets.

```
make assets-update
```

... which in turn wraps:

```
app/console bazinga:js-translation:dump
app/console assets:install
app/console assetic:dump
@if [ ! -h web/storage ]; then \
    ln --symbolic ../data/storage web/storage; \
```

Once I did that, the issue went away.